# php link cloak via base64 encryption -- need help

Tags: php, cloaking

I used to have a script that basically base64 encoded the link and then the redirect PHP page would decode it and send you off to the page.

I don't know what I am doing wrong and PHP is not my best skill, just looking for some help.

Link on page:

```
<a href="http://www.XXXXXX.com/find.php?shop=<?php echo urlencode(base64_encode("long ass link goes here"));  ?>">Test</a>
```

find.php:

```
< ?php

    $request_id = $_GET ['shop'];
    $site = base64_decode($request_id);

    header( 'Location: $site' ) ;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use $variables in strings, use double quotes:

```
header("Location: $site");
```

Or concatenate the strings:

```
header('Location: '.$site);
```

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

+++ But better store that value into $_SESSION, because users can change it and it will bring up errors.

Comment: when i see where the URL is pointing to on the bottom of my browser, it's definitely not encoding the URL properly, any ideas?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question =/

Comment: when i mouse over the link, in the status bar (bottom part of browser), i don't see the URL being base64 encoded, it's showing: 'http://www.XXXXXX.com/find.php?shop=<?php echo urlencode(base64_encode'

Comment: It seems like that php is not executed.
Does the file that contains this code has .php extension? Does that file enough permissions to be executed? Does any other code on that page is getting executed?

Comment: its on a post in my wordpress blog

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get your php executed inside your post? Than it will not be ever executed. Just imagine that somebody will add a comment or will have author level to post smth... He'll can create a php shell and it would be a huge security hole.

Comment: it will be a static page, w/ no comments. here is an image when i hover over the link... http://i51.tinypic.com/9u7xh0.png

Answer (score 0):

If you copied and pasted that second code, try removing the space between `<` and `?`. It should be `<?php`.

Comment: i fixed that, but like i said to the other answer, when i view where my original link is going, it doesnt look like my URL is getting base64 encoded

Comment: It should show something 
http://XXXXXX.com/find.php?shop=aHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tL3F1ZXN0aW9ucy80NDg2MzYwL3BocC1saW5rLWNsb2FrLXZpYS1iYXNlNjQtZW5jcnlwdGlvbi1uZWVkLWhlbHA%3D
Are you saying that this is not what you are seeing?

Comment: i can see the link it's creating and its not actually base64 encrypting the long link